# Bluetooth serial communication

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to connect my Windows 8 computer to my Raspberry Pi with a Bluetooth dongle plug in RPi. My final objective is to send serial data through RPi and the Raspberry will then send these informations to a DSP. I successful the pairing with my computer, but then if I get it right I need to create a RFcomm channel between Raspberry and the computer. When I write this in my Raspberry shell:

```
sdptool add sp
rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0
```

I have no way to accept the channel on my computer. I think I need a serial terminal emulator but I don't find any for Windows 8 on the web. I've tried BT serial terminal but the software don't even see my RPi...
Someone have some clues for me on what kind of software I should use or another way my goal can be done?

Comment: Have you tried cygwin or mingw for a terminal emulator?

Comment: What sort of bluetooth dongle are you using on the Pi (e.g. a serial one, or a USB one).

Comment: i went throught my trouble the real issue was that my PC had no bluetoothCOM port. I create one in control panel-BT. Then everything work fine! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I went through my pain with 2 step

First. I needed to add a BT com port on my PC this was achieved in the control panel BT. there is several video on youtube showing how.

Second. adding in the rfcomm config the right binding and then running a python script that connect to the rfcomm desired

thats for the rfcomm config

```
rfcomm{
    Bind yes;
    Adresse ; PC MAC adresse
    Defaut
    Defaut
}
```

and here a link on what kind of python code you can build

[Using python with bluetooth to communicate](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24028/using-python-with-bluetooth-to-communicate)